# Reading a REG_RESOURCE_LIST value from registry

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I'm trying to read a value of type REG_RESOURCE_LIST from the registry, but without success.
The specific value I'm trying to read is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\{YourNetworkInterface}\{GUID}\Control\AllocConfig`.
You can find this value by going to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI`, and searching for a key that his subkey (the {GUID} part in the path) have a value named `Class` with a value of `Net`.
Or you can just search for it.

The strange thing is, when I'm opening the `Control` key through code, and calling `GetValueNames()` I'm getting the `AllocConfig` value name, but when calling `GetValue("AllocConfig")` I'm getting null (not null in reality).
Also, in ProccessMonitor, I see that when calling `GetValue("AllocConfig")` the result is `Buffer Overflow`.
Any help will be appriciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you using `Microsoft.Win32.Registry`?

Answer (score 3):

To get a REG_RESOURCE_LIST, you need to use RegQueryValueEx().  The value you should expect in the lpType out parameter is 8 ([see here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84642bd4-1dc6-4ae9-bd64-d5e0d985e347/how-to-read-regresourcelist-data-from-registry)). The data you get back in the lpData out parameter is a [CM_RESOURCE_LIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Call RegQueryValueEx first to get the size of the list, allocate a buffer of that size, call ReqQueryValueEx to fill in the buffer, and cast the buffer pointer to PCM_RESOURCE_LIST. The CM_RESOURCE_LIST documentation linked above tells you how to iterate over the list and extract the contents.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/ischen/2007/12/04/querying-device-hardware-resources-from-the-windows-registry-using-c/

The c# project properly decodes REG_RESOURCE_LIST data structure from registry which is based on CM_RESOURCE_LIST structure that is a list that contains many CM_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTORs.